# Getting a table on a date

Tags: java

You and your date are trying to get a table at a restaurant. "you" is the stylishness of your clothes, in the range 0..10, and "date" is the stylishness of your date's clothes. The result getting the table is either “No”, “Maybe” , or “Yes”. If either of you is very stylish, 8 or more, then the result is “Yes”. With the exception that if either of you has style of 2 or less, then the result is “No”. Otherwise the result is “Maybe”. Given 2 integers “you” and “date” check whether you are able to get a table.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int you = scan.nextInt();
    int date = scan.nextInt();

    if((you >= 8 && date > 2) || (date >=8 && you >2))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else if((you >= 8 && date <=2) || (you <= 2 && date >= 8) || (you <= 2 && date <= 2))
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```

}

Is there anything missing? The online judge is giving me a score of 79/100

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: This is probably the first SO question involving table and date that did not involve databases or timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this statement:

else if((you >= 8 && date <=2) || (you <= 2 && date >= 8) || (you <= 2 && date <= 2))

Is this valid on the last clause?  It doesn't necessarily say it's a NO if you both are <= 2.  Only if one of you is a 8+ and the other is a 2-.  If your remove it, it might give you a better score.

Comment: it gave me a 70/100. It's saying that if either of us is less than 2... so I should also take the case where both of us are less than 2.

Comment: change it to else if (you <=2 || date <= 2) ONLY.